# How to display alt tags in img src?

Tags: images, title

I'm working off a custom theme which they entirely left out including the alt tag in the img source.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_field('image')['sizes']['large']; ?>">
```

I was searching to find the answer and found this to add, but does not work:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_field('image')['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>>">
```

I'm still pretty much a novice with Wordpress templates. Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: Can you get ahold of the image ID? There's [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) which looks fine and dandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Advanced custom fields plugin. 
The documentation for images: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

To display the alt-tag for example, you can use this snippet:

```
$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty( $image ) ) {
    $alt = $image['alt'];
    ...
    echo '<img src="..." alt=" . $alt .">'
}
```